# Gradle upgrade from 1.3 to 2.6 - will it impact current work flow & artifact outputs

Tags: gradle

Currently our project is using Gradle-1.3 version and we have a plan of upgrading it to Gradle-2.6 version inorder to implement artifactory in it.

Need to know if we upgrade gradle from 1.3 to 2.6 will there be impact to current artifact creation and if there any specific exclusion in Gradle-2.6/higher which were actually part of inclusion in Gradle-1.3 version?

Answer (score 0):

There are some breaking changes between 1.3 and 2.6. To get most of them I would advise you to take a look at the according release notes. Basic functionality that has worked with 1.3 most likely is working in 2.6 as the Gradle Team is quite cautious in introducing breaking changes. You should just try building your project with Gradle 2.6 and compare the outputs. Keep in mind that already Gradle 2.10 is released which offers some quite nice performance improvements for incremental builds in comparison to 2.6.